# How do I prevent Jest from trying to execute my .eslintrc.js as a test file?

Tags: jestjs, eslint

I'm trying to set up a new project which uses both ESLint and Jest. I also want to use eslint-plugin-jest, to get Jest-specific linting rules. I *don't* want those rules to apply to non-test files, though.

Usually, the way I'd accomplish something like this is to create a root `.eslintrc.js` in the root of the project and a folder-specific `.eslintrc.js` in the folder needing special rules. This appears to work fine for ESLint, but Jest tries to execute `__tests__/.eslintrc.js` as a test file and complains that it doesn't have any tests.

How can I tell Jest to ignore my ESLint configuration file?

Project structure:

- `.eslintrc.js`
- `package.json`
- `jest.config.js`
- `lib/`

  - `index.js`
- `__tests__/`

  - `.eslintrc.js`
  - `index.test.js`